# Server slow, lost connection to network printer

Tags: windows-server-2003

Server slow, lost connection to network printer and users who log off take 30 minutes before the login windows appears (installing some net agent?!?)

I rebooted the windows 2003 Server and everything came back on.

Why?

Answer (score 1):

How long was it between your last reboots? Check your logs for any issues that might have come up.

Comment: in event viewer / applications I had the error:  Failed to load Terminal Server Profile path. Note that the profile path must be less than 256 characters in length. User Name: administrator Domain: ICTO 

followed by:

Unexpected error <<0xc1050000 - Network problems are preventing connection to the Microsoft Exchange Server computer. An unexpected, unknown error has occurred. Microsoft Exchange Server Information Store ID no: 80040115-0514-000006bf>> occurred. 

on msexchangesa

Comment: Last reboot was about 4 months ago

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the event logs on your domain controller? Maybe you are having some authentication issues.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same exact issue from PCs with Vista or XP connecting to Windows server 2003 via Remote Desktop. I reboot the server every day. It started recently; must be some windows update that caused this. When I reboot the problem is fixed until a few hours later when it happens again.